# Can't use URL for File

Tags: java, file, url, resources

My old version works, but if I try to export to runnable Jar File, it doesn't load the txt file.

```
public String jarLocation = getClass().getProtectionDomain()
        .getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
public File txt = new File(jarLocation + "/images/gewinne.txt");
```

After that I tried with get Resource, but the File can't load the URL part :/ I am lost

```
public URL urlGewinne = Kalender.class.getResource("/images/gewinne.txt");
public File txt = new File(urlGewinne); // ERROR

public void txtLesen() throws IOException {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txt));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            gewinne.add(line);
        }

        br.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that the getPath() method of URL *does not* convert a `file:` URL into a valid file path.  This is evident if you try it with a URL like `file:/C:/Program%20Files/`.  The correct way to convert a `file:` URL into a file is with `Paths.get(url.toURI())`, or, if you must use java.io.File, `new File(url.toURI())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is obvious: resource is not a file. 
The resource taken from jar file is a part of this jar, entry of jar, whatever, but not a separate file found in file system.

The good news however that you do not need file at all. If successfully you get resource you can get its stream directly and read from this stream:

Change line

```
URL urlGewinne = Kalender.class.getResource("/images/gewinne.txt");
```

to

```
InputStream urlGewinne = Kalender.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/gewinne.txt");
```

and this line:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txt));
```

to

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(txt));
```

The rest of your code should work.

Comment: While all you say is true, I didn't +1 for a simple reason: you do not use try-with-resources!

Comment: @fge, *I* do not use? Or OP does not use? I've just answered the OP's question. I can add a 2 hours lecture about the OP's coding style and how to improve it but it is not the right place to do.

Comment: The fact is, ultimately, you end up with a `Closeable` which is an `AutoCloseable` --> use try-with-resources!